# Which is a better way to code? and why?

Tags: jquery, performance

Which is a better way to write code? Below I have two ways to delete an item along with its parent. Is it better to write a function and then call that function on clicking the trash icon (First Way) or directly delete it without writing any new functions(Second Way).

There could be two scenarios:

1. I want to repeat a certain action again and again
2. I want to do this action only once.

In the example below I want this only once.

**First Way:**

```
function deleteTodoItem(e, item) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(item).parent().fadeOut('slow', function() { 
    $(item).parent().remove();
  });
}
$(".middlepanel").on('click', '.fa.fa-trash', function(e){
    var item = this; 
    deleteTodoItem(e, item)
})
```

**Second Way:**

```
 $('.middlepanel').on('click','.fa.fa-trash',function(){
     $(this).parent().fadeOut('slow',function(){ 
        $(this).parent().remove();
     }
 })
```

Comment: I think you answered the question yourself. If you plan to reuse the code, then create a method. Otherwise, no problem in just writing it once in the event itself

Comment: Does this affect the execution speed of the code? Suppose I only want to do this action once and have two options to write that code as shown above

Comment: If you want to use the function more than once, than I would use the first way. If you only use the function once, than I would use the second way. I always try to use the [KISS principe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and the [DNRY principe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: In my opinion, the differences in execution speed will be so minimal, you can ignore it. We must me talking about 0.00001ms or something :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific "Better" way in this specific example, because basically the function is just to wrap something that the event is using.

However, still the first code snippet is good in this context, because modification might be limited to and only one place of change. - i guess !!!